# Codeigniter routing behavior with the controllers magic method __call

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes, magic-methods

The segments in a URI normally follow this pattern in Codeigniter:

XYZ.com/Class/Method/param1/param2

This works as expected when the called method is defined in the controller, but nothing works if I supply the URI with some undefined method to invoke the __call magic method that takes care of any undefined method.

__call is only invoked if its called from within the controller itself, not when I call some undefined method from the URI

Any explanation?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CodeIgniter, there is [`_remap`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping).  So if you go to

> XYZ.com/Class/UndefinedMethod/param1/param2

then `_remap` will be called (actually `_remap` will always be called, so we need to make sure that methods that do exist are called correctly).

```
function _remap($method, $params=array()){
    $funcs = get_class_methods($this);
    if(in_array($method, $funcs)){ // We are trying to go to a method in this class
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
    }
    // else do something else
}
```

Comment: _remap works, but it always get called regardless of what your URI contains. no matter if the called method is defined or not.. I need only to take care of undefined method, plus why __call doesn't work in the 1st place?

Comment: Yeah, `_remap` will always get called, I added code that should take care of that for you though.  `__call` doesn't work, because that's how CodeIgniter works.  `_call` works in Models (and Libraries), but not Controllers.  That's why there is `_remap`.

Comment: I didn't want to do a call to call a defined function. I just want it just to take care of any undefined functions. _remap is not a __call, they are different, but since this is the only way codeigniter works, so the question is solved.

Comment: Yeah, CodeIgniter can be kinda weird, that's just how it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Look in the server (Apache?) log file.  Undoubtedly you will see PHP errors which caused processing to abort.  Unless you cover undefined functions by remapping them to an error page, random URLs will cause "nothing" to seem to happen.